# WPF RichTextBox: AppendText, TextRange and the trailing newline

Tags: c#, wpf, newline, richtextbox

I am reading a text file's contents into a RichTextBox like this:

```cs
string contents = File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
myRichTextBox.AppendText(contents);
```

I am using the RichTextBox to automatically apply some syntax highlighting of sorts. When I try reading the unformatted text as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-extract-the-text-content-from-a-richtextbox) to save it back to the file, things happen:

1. A newline (\r\n) is added to the back of the file, which I don't want unless the user explicitly adds this newline.
2. When I load the file again, the newline is not displayed in the RichTextEdit, even if it is present in the file.

How can I change this, so that the RichTextBox displays and returns exactly the contents of the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newline `\r\n` (CR/LF) is part of the text formatting in the `RichTextBox` control. Each paragraph while converting to the text will be appended by the `\r\n`.

This is means when a user press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button a new paragraph with `\r\n` is adding to the `RichTextBox` control. And when [`StringFromRichTextBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-extract-the-text-content-from-a-richtextbox?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) method, described in the Microsoft documentation is used to extract the text content from a `RichTextBox` it will return a string in which all paragraphs are separated by the `\r\n`.

The explanations regarding the comments above:

> A newline (\r\n) is added to the back of the file, which I don't want unless the user explicitly adds this newline.

A newline `\r\n` is adding to the end of the file only as a part of the each paragraph ending.

**NOTE:** If it is necessary to save and thereafter to load the saved document the `TextRange.Save()` and `TextRange.Load()` methods can be used:

```cs
public void SaveRtf(RichTextBox rtb, string file)
{
    var range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        range.Load(stream.BaseStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}

public void LoadRtf(RichTextBox rtb, string file)
{
    var range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        range.Save(stream.BaseStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```

If to save the whole `RuchTextBox` content the `new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text` will be used than any text formatting after restoring will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work? contents.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

Comment: Unfortunately not, the behavior is the same.